# What status code should I return for a connection error?

Tags: http, http-headers

I'm writing a service that returns data about another request to the consumer (for example, retrieving the un-shortened URL from a bitly or t.co address). In most situations, I can return a status code to mirror the code I received from the server, but what status code is most appropriate when my service is unable to connect to the requested URL (if it doesn't exist, for example)? I was thinking `400 Bad Request` or `408 Request Timeout`, but is there a best practice here?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`503 Service Unavailable` seems like an appropriate choice.  The `4xx` codes are meant to indicate the client did something wrong.  In the case you specify, it's a service error.

Comment: My reasoning was that *my* service is functioning properly, but the client attempted to request a nonexistent URL through it, which struck me as a client error.

Comment: How do you know it's nonexistant, or if it's not responding, or if the internet connection is down, or if the routing tables are wonky?  I routinely get `50x` errors from my corporate proxy when the network flaked out.  "Service Unavailable" is agnostic -- it doesn't know if it's been improperly entered or if there's an actual flaw in the remote service.  It's just "unavailable".

Answer (score 6):

`502 Bad Gateway`, since you're acting as a proxy server.

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 502 Bad Gateway server error response code indicates that the server, **while acting as a gateway or proxy**, received an invalid response from the upstream server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502

Comment: But what about the case that OP suggests - where there is no response?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer IMO `503` means the proxy server itself is down for maintenance, or unhealthy like overloaded, while `502` indicates the status of the upstream server. So I'd use `502` for the case that no response from the upstream server.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting and debatable. What if the IP(hostname) is unavailable temporarily? 503 is more accurate in that sense. If at all someone is trying to connect to an IP(hostname) that doesn't exists (which is beyond the realms of gateway to determine) a bad gateway may look appropriate.

However 504 could be more realistic as to convey what system has attempted and that would convey a timeout and not received any response from the upstream.